# Extending Grid Props For Custom Breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with the latest Material-UI (MUI) JavaScript package, and I'm heavily customizing theme to achieve a particular design system. In doing so, I'm redefining breakpoints, and adding a new breakpoint within my theme object:

```
xxs: 0
```

In terms of functionality, I am able to use this new breakpoint with ease, using the breakpoint functions, and in a Grid component, etc.

The problem is TypeScript is throwing errors in relation to Grid, when used in this way to specify a 'column size':

```
<Grid item xxs={12}...
```

I am able to augment the BreakpointOverrides interface to accommodate my new breakpoint for most other cases:

```
declare module '@mui/system/createTheme/createBreakpoints' {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xxs: true;
  }
}
```

However, augmenting to allow Grid components to allow usage of the custom breakpoint isn't as straight forward.  Grid is a type, derived by:

```
declare const Grid: OverridableComponent<GridTypeMap>;

export type GridProps<
  D extends React.ElementType = GridTypeMap['defaultComponent'],
  P = {},
> = OverrideProps<GridTypeMap<P, D>, D>;

export default Grid;
```

Where GridTypeMap is defined as

```
export interface GridTypeMap<P = {}, D extends React.ElementType = 'div'> {
  props: P &
    SystemProps<Theme> & {
  <<All Listed Props, 'children', 'container', 'item', 'lg' so on>>
  };
  defaultComponent: D;
 }
```

Attempting to augment the `GridTypeMap` is not going well, I'm not sure what form it should take to augment correctly. What can I do here to have TypeScript throwing errors when setting `xxs={number}` on a Grid component?

(The functionality under the hood works as expected, though.)